# No cp or git command is executed on docker-compose

Tags: docker, shell, docker-compose

This is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services: 
    app:
        image: company/image
        ports:
            - "5000:5000"
        working_dir: /path/to/git/repository
        command: sh -c "git reset --hard origin/main"
        command: git reset --hard origin/main
        command: cp /src/module/menu.json /src/menu.json
        command: sh -c "cp /src/module/menu.json /src/menu.json"
        command: dummy
        command: sh -c "dummy"
        volumes: 
            - /path/on/local:/path/on/docker
        command: sh -c "echo 'hello from inside docker'"
```

When I run `docker-compose up`, I only see this:

> Recreating module_app_1 ... done
> Attaching to module_app_1
> app_1  | hello from inside docker
> module_app_1 exited with code 0

And I can inspect the container using `docker-compose exec app` and I can see that none of the `cp` and `git` commands are executed and I also see no error at all in the output.

Also `dummy` is apparently a command that does not exist on this container. Why do I see no errors for that?

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

> none of the `cp` and `git` commands are executed and I also see no error at all in the output.

Yes, because you added multiple `command:` lines in the `docker-compose.yml`, while this property is intended to specify **a single command** (just to recall, a Docker container is intended to run just one program).

As a result, you only see the outcome of the last `command:` line, which overwrites the previous ones:

> app_1 | hello from inside docker

Still, you can do the following to address your use case (even if it may be not very idiomatic):

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services: 
    app:
        image: company/image
        ports:
            - "5000:5000"
        working_dir: /path/to/git/repository
        command: |
          sh -e -c "
            git reset --hard origin/main
            cp /src/module/menu.json /src/menu.json
            echo 'hello from inside docker'
          "
        volumes: 
            - /path/on/local:/path/on/docker
```

This answer specifically relies on the so-called [block style of YAML](https://yaml-multiline.info/), and the [shell option `-e`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/sh.html#tag_04_128_04) is recommended to exit immediately if one of the shell commands fails.

Comment: I wonder why VS Code didn't complain about multiple `command` lines. I've also installed `Docker` extension on VS Code. Thank you.